# Django: Upload database associated file to remote server

Tags: django, database, file, upload, remote-server

Hello community of stack overflow.

Im having a big problem.

Well this is my scenery: I have two projects of Django, and the users model have a ImageField, When I create in both Porjects the users I want upload this field to another server, for example I have a Droplet in DigitalOcean just with apache, and I want upload all the media data in this server!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: Hi, the question is: How can i upload the image in a droplet from django?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the storage application, at the end, the system is uploading media files to AWS S3!